# How to ask for a raise

Tags: career-development, raise

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

I've been working for almost a year for a startup and I feel like I learned a lot and grew very fast to be one of the best employees there. Every time I get very positive feedback from everyone. So, i decided to ask for a pay raise, because I already asked lower than market rate at the beginning, hoping to have a higher probability to get hired and then prove myself and then ask for a raise. I sent email to my manager and CTO thanking them for an opportunity for growth and asked them to increase my rate by a few dollars per hour more. My manager told me that he would talk tot he CTO about it. They had a meeting, but they didnt say anything to me after that. It has been a week already. What should I do?

Comment: Please don't cross post - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148653/how-long-should-i-wait-after-asking-for-a-raise

Comment: This is not duplicate. The other question talks about being underpaid, the accepted answer says, you are getting a good raise so no complains there. Here there is no raise. The issue is legitimate and may I say same with me. The only problem I see is a bit too localized though.

Comment: I agree with @enthusiast. This is becoming rather common in "salary raise" questions.